How to build bench with a rocking top rectangular section?
I want to build a metal bench, maybe 2m x 50cm x 40cm(W). A bit like a weights bench. The flat top rectangular section you sit or lay on should rock maybe 30 degrees to each side. What parts would be best to achieve this rocking motion. Some kind of metal shaft on the bottom and somehow attach the flat top section to this?

examine a rocking chair ... some rocking chairs have a curved bottom to achieve the motion ... some have a flat bottom and contain a rocking mechanism to achieve the motion

Totally not what I'm talking about. I'm using metal.

what are you talking about then? ... please add a diagram ... it is unclear how the comment about metal relates to what I said

https://i.ibb.co/pPCdfs7/20240429-090206.jpg so the seat A has to be able to rotate on B (the frame) I need this rotation say 30 degrees each side. All made of metal I think aluminum. The frame will be a bit thicker than the drawing looks.

please add the picture to your question ... click the edit button. then click the icon with the mountain and sun

I did add an image click the link in my last message.
